# array results turns 0 in my UNION query

Tags: php, mysql, sql

```
   <?php
    $con=mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
     if (!$con)
      {
      die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
   }
mysql_select_db("dbjobsheets", $con);
     $result = mysql_query ("select * from checklist union select * from checklistdailylogs;");

   while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result));
```

i tried everything in google but no luck. i tried also the join command and i got an error of mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource.

still error in fetch array.

```
  $result = mysql_query ("select frequency from checklist union select daily from checklistdailylogs;");
```

i got no error on this but when i try to add another column like this

```
$result = mysql_query ("select frequency, sla from checklist union select daily, actualstart from checklistdailylogs;");
```

got mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource.

Comment: write valid sql `select checklistdailylogs` ??

Comment: +1 ^^^ - `while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result));` ok, and then what? Semi-colon stops right there.

Comment: while thirsty, drunk rum

Comment: Seeing your edit and adding the `*` you're still missing the `from`. See the answer given to you below by Harvey.

Comment: @Fred-ii- i just want to register the array on my sql query after the while statement i'm calling the column in my tables but i having a hard time getting the array of multiple columns from 2 tables

Comment: Since it hasn't been posted yet: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php

Answer (score 1):

Your brackets are outside the SQL string, also your second table has no fields specified and the missing `from` for the other table selection; I assume you mean:

```
$result = mysql_query("(select * from checklist) UNION (select * from checklistdailylogs)");
```

Comment: My bad, just remove the brackets completely.

Comment: `select * FROOOOOOMMMMMMM`

Comment: I am having a bad day :) For reference the correct SQL would be (assuming both tables have matching columns); "select * from checklist union select * from checklistdailylogs;"

Comment: @Dagon I wanted to change it to `FROOOOOOMMMMMMM` but I would have gotten a slap cross the head by the SQL gods. ;)

Comment: im calling all my table names to "from" to confuse others who come after me. select `from` from `from` where `from`="from"

Comment: i added from and copy paste the codes above i still got an mysql_fetch_array() error

Comment: Instead of * specify the column names, make sure types, and number of columns match. If you still need more help run "show create table checklist;" and 'show create table checklistdailylogs;" and post the results for further help.

Comment: @Dagon Why stop there, randomly name `tables select, where, update, delete` and if you want to live dangerously `drop`.

Comment: $result = mysql_query ("select frequency from checklist       union select daily from checklistdailylogs;"); <---- i got no error but when i try to add another column i have an error $result = mysql_query ("select frequency, rts from checklist union select daily, actualstart from checklistdailylogs;");